# Can a READY->IDLE state transition occur because of no RPC activity over a certain period in gRPC C++?

Tags: grpc, channel, grpc-c++

This link (https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/md_doc_connectivity-semantics-and-api.html) mentions that a READY->IDLE state transition could occur when there is - "No RPC activity on channel for IDLE_TIMEOUT". I read somewhere that this is not applicable for gRPC C++. I wanted confirm if this is true? Is there some other documentation where I can find this information?

Also, I now assume that a READY->IDLE transition will only occur if an explicit disconnection occurs. Is this a valid assumption to make for gRPC C++?